# How to ignore exceptions for children before rendering the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I'm writing a `WithLoading` component which will render the children if loading is false and render a loading text otherwise. Children contain parameters of a response from an ajax call. But when it is creating the children (not rendering them) the response is null and it throws an exception. How can I ignore the exceptions before being rendered?

Here is the code sample

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

const WithLoading = props => {
  if (props.loading) {
    return <div>loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return props.children;
  }
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setResponse({ data: "data" });
    }, 1000);
  });
  return (
      <WithLoading loading={!response}>
        <div>{response.data}</div>
      </WithLoading>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: you can write a condition if(response !== null) then render children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `children` a callback instead of an element:

```
const WithLoading = props => {
  if (props.loading) {
    return <div>loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return props.children();
  }
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setResponse({ data: "data" });
    }, 1000);
  });
  const children = useCallback(
    () => <div>{response.data}</div>,
    [response]
  );

  return (
    <WithLoading loading={!response}>
      {children}
    </WithLoading>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit dmr38]

Answer (score 0):

It could be worked-around as follows:

Inside your child component `MyComponent`, you have `response.data`, which is `null`/`undefined` at the very first mount of the component, you can always run a checkup as follow `response && response.data`, adding the `response &&`, will be checking if the `response` object exists, if so, will return the `response.data` array you want.